# Unable to remove row in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I keep getting an error saying `Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (2)`. I have a tableView with sections and each sections contains an array of strings representing the row. I am also trying to do the delete through a button which I am adding to the cell on cellforRowAt.

```
extension RequestsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myArr[section].myItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RequestViewCell", for: indexPath) as! RequestViewCell

        cell.description.text = "\(myArr[indexPath.section].myItems[indexPath.row])"
        cell.declineBtn.tag = (indexPath.section * 100) + indexPath.row
        cell.declineBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(declineRequest(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        cell.acceptBtn.tag = (indexPath.section * 100) + indexPath.row
        cell.acceptBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(acceptRequest(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
```

and then the method being called is supposed to remove the row if decline btn is pressed

```
@objc func declineRequest(sender: UIButton) {
        let section = sender.tag / 100
        let row = sender.tag % 100
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)

        myArr.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
```

I tried to add the protocol methods too 'commit editingstyle' to .delete and canEditRowAt, but with no luck as I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed the inconsistencies. I am trying to remove the row within the section. So i guess up until I remove the last element in that row, i wouldn't be deleting the section right, atleast thats how I thought it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `declineRequest` you have to delete

```
myArr[section].myItems.remove(at: row)
```

If you want to remove also the section if the items array becomes empty write

```
// if there is one item left delete the section (including the row)
if myArr[section].myItems.count == 1 {
    myArr.remove(at: section)
    tableView.deleteSections([section], with: .fade)
} else { // otherwise delete the row
    myArr[section].myItems.remove(at: row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

Comment: and then how would I remove the section after the last element (row) is removed? Im not sure how to get the sections parameter with the way I marking the rows.